# Headers in book format

Tags: header-footer, capitalization

I am writting my thesis. I don't want the headers in each chapter to appear just in capital letters. Can I override the class file to get the header as " My First Chapter"?

Comment: See also @VincentFormond's comment on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78551/98394 re `\let\MakeUppercase=\relax`.

Answer (score 12):

Alternative using [fancyhdr](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr):

```
\documentclass{book}
% book defaults
%  headers
%   even pages
%    left: page number
%    right: CHAPTER 1. MY FIRST CHAPTER
%   odd pages
%    left: empty
%    right: page number
%  footers: empty
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all headers and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove rule between header and text
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage} % put page number in left header on even pages,
                            % right header on odd pages
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} % remove uppercase on chapter title
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % remove "Chapter N." prefix

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My First Chapter}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

You didn't reveal your document class. Assuming you're using the standard `book` class (or `report` with `\pagestyle{headings}`, you have to locally disable the `\MakeUppercase` command which is hardcoded in the header's definition. One way to do so is to load the `scrpage2` package (part of [`KOMA-Script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)) with the `nouppercase` option.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[nouppercase]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My First Chapter}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Indeed I'm using book class. Now I wonder if Memoir works the same.

Comment: @Trevis With `memoir`, you don't need to load `scrpage2` and may simply use `\nouppercaseheads` in the preamble.