# Headings in report documentclass

Tags: header-footer, capitalization, report

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Headers in book format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49168/headers-in-book-format)

I am working with report documentclass. I have this in my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\pagestyle{headings}
```

I would like to get lower case headings (except for the first letter of each word), like this:

> Chapter 1. Literature Review

What I have so far is:

> CHAPTER 1. LITERATURE REVIEW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markright {{%                                    %%% original \MakeUppercase
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```