# How to properly include long chapter titles into headings?

Tags: formatting, chapters, thesis

I am writing a PhD thesis which contains a long chapter title:

> On the edge of universality of sequential P systems

When I use standard headings pagestyle, then the title in the heading overflows and it looks ugly:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany,pagenumber=footcenter]{book}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\chapter{On the edge of universality of sequential P systems}
\section{Active membranes}
\pagebreak
second page
\end{document}
```

> [image]

There are other options, e.g. wrapping long title to the next line. It is somewhat better, but it is still pretty unreadable:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany,pagenumber=footcenter]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\chapter{On the edge of universality of sequential P systems}
\section{Active membranes}
\pagebreak
second page
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Another option is to display shorter version of chapter title in the heading:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany,pagenumber=footcenter]{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter[On the edge of universality of seq\dots]{On the edge of universality of sequential P systems}
\section{Active membranes}
\pagebreak
second page
\end{document}
```

> [image]

I think, anything is possible. But what is the best practice for these long titles? My department has no rules for this, even this [manual](http://www.siam.org/journals/pdf/stylemanual.pdf) has no mention of it. I am asking for a general recommendation: What would you do?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Best practice is to avoid long titles ;-)

Comment: Added source codes

Comment: If long titles are unavoidable, use the optional argument to provide a shorter version for the header and ToC.

Comment: I agree with Gonzalo Medina, use shortened title.  When doing so, make it meaningful/useful.  In your case I would suggested something like "shortened P systems".  In any case the  "On the edge of" is not needed in the short version.

Comment: as for other commentators I'd suggest using a short title, but a complete short title not just cut off with `\ldots`

Comment: If you have such long titles DO YOU REALLY WANT ALL CAPS TEXT IN THE HEADER, IT SEEMS TO MAKE IT HARDER TO SET AND HARDER TO READ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle nice thought (the best so far), btw caps are default for the book class: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49168/headers-in-book-format

Comment: Yes I know they are the default, and are fine if your titles are "Introduction" but I'd change the default here. The default `headings` page style also only uses either a chapter or a section title it doesn't try to put both on the same page.

Comment: Exactly, you are obviously at the beginning of typesetting your thesis so you'll certainly will learn a lot about which classes offer you options you deem more suitable to your needs. You can customize *a lot* in LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

I would abbreviate the title to a complete phrase, not just truncate it with `\ldots`
Also I would change the default marks not to uppercase. In the default settings the chapter titles are probably intended to be shorter and each page only has a chapter or a section heading, not both.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
 \markboth{\if@mainmatter
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
          \fi #1}{}}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{%
 \markright {%
          \thesection. \ %
        #1}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter[edge of universality]
{On the edge of universality of sequential P systems}
\section{Active membranes}
\pagebreak
second page
\end{document}
```